# Android: How to preserve SurfaceView contents when activity is paused

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

I'm creating a game and I'm trying to get the app to save the current game state when the activity is paused. I've drawn all the game elements on a SurfaceView operating in a separate thread. Additionally, the game elements are all randomly generated when the activity is created. Currently, whenever I press the home button or open another activity from the game activity, when I return to the activity all the elements are completely regenerated, which should only occur if the activity has been destroyed. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you implement onPause and onResume methods in your activity?

Comment: In my main activity, I have onPause and onResume, but I have another class for my surfaceView which has surfaceCreated and surfaceDestroyed. The surfaceview is referenced in the xml of my main activity.